# JS Dialog Box change color of close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the color of the `Close Button`. So far I managed to change the color of `Title Bar` and the `Body` but, for the button I can't manage to change it.

**Current Code**

```
 $("#dialogTest").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    title: "<img src='../../Content/Images/icon/icons_02.png'/> RECORD HELP! MISSING DATA!",
    buttons: {
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        }
    }
}).css({ 'background-color': '#fceab0' }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "red");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your Close function to:

```
    Close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
```